# ¿Cómo importar de Excel a Mysql con seelctor de columnas?

Tags: php, excel

Llamando a la función PHPExcel, puedo importar un excel con, por ejemplo, 5 columnas a una tabla MySQL que tenga la misma estructura, lo hace correcto. Es decir, si la estructura del excel es:

- Columna A -> nombre Columna B -> apellido Columna C -> edad

y en Mysql tengo una tabla con columnas nombre, apellido y edad, perfecto.
El problema es que no sé como hacer para que, si el fichero excel viene con las columans cambiadas, o por ejemplo, con más columnas:

- Columna A -> NIF Columna B -> nombre Columna C -> Ciudad Columna D ->
  apellido Columna E -> telefono Columna F -> edad

Y lo que quiero es importar solo los datos de nombre, apellido y edad. Al no coincidir las estructuras, ¿puede hacerse un selector/asignador de columnas?
¿Se puede importar y que cree dinámicamente la tabla con esa otra estructura?
Gracias anticipadas

Answer (score 0):

Con la librería PHPExcel, que en su versión actual cambió por [PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/) puedes leer la planilla, recorrerla y guardar en un arreglo los datos en el orden que necesites para luego realizar tus consultas de inserción en MySQL.

Lo que necesitarás es algún modo de identificar las columnas, por ejemplo, si sabes que habrá alguna columna con el título "Nombre" pero no sabes su posición, deberás hacer un primer proceso que las identifique y luego recorrer el resto de la planilla para generar los SQL que correspondan.

Comment: Hola @Muc, graciasd por responder. El problema es que soy nuevo en todo esto y no se bien como hacerlo. Estoy buscando ejemplos, pero solo veo como leer ficheros completos con una estructura definida.

Comment: Hola @oraculo, armé este código https://github.com/leeway-academy/importFromExcel que espero te ayude (Intentaré hacer un video explicándolo pero aún no he tenido tiempo). Saludos!

Comment: Hola @oraculo, acá está un video explicando bien el script: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpMR0p6sihA

Comment: Hola@Muc, lo primero mil gracias por tu ayuda. El script está perfecto, pero el problema es que las columnas, aparte de no saber el orden en el que van en Excel, tampoco siempre tienen el mismo nombre.

Comment: @oraculo uu... pero ahí tenés un problema serio... ¿tenés algo que se mantenga constante? (El tipo de datos o algún otro atributo que puedas usar para identificar las columnas? De otra forma vas a necesitar algún archivo auxiliar de definición de la planilla o algo así...

Comment: el único dato que se que tendrán todos los ficheros, es alfanumerico, y en cada uno vendrá con un nombre diferente y con una posición diferente. He probado varias opciones para leer Excel completos y pasarlos a tabla, pero en ningún lado explica como mapear las columnas. No soluciona todo pero al menos, el paso de exportar el excel a csv si.

Comment: Hola @Muc, para probar el código de tu ejemplo en un servidor remoto, ¿basta con estos dos ficheros que indicas? veo que llama a un auload.php dentro de /vendor y al descargar de github no lo veo. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Hola @oraculo, necesitas instalar las dependencias usando composer. Aquí tienes algo de información: https://academy.leewayweb.com/que-es-composer/